# Google Analytics Data Studio - Adding Users to a table changes number of Sessions

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I am using a free version of Google Analytics and I am trying to put together a simple table in Google Data studio.
The table I want would be a flat table and would have the following fields:

Rows: Country (the native Google Analytics dimension)

Columns: Sessions, Users (native Google Analytics metrics without any adjustments)

I started with adding Country as rows and added one column for Sessions but when I am adding Users as a second column, the number of Sessions changes for each country (it's "random" increase or decrease change)

Checks already done:
For the same time frame as selected in my table:

1. In Google Analytics Standard Reports > Audience > Geo > Location > Country (Primary Dimension) number of Sessions for each Country aligns with the  Google Data Studio Sessions number that I see when Users column is not added.
2. In GA Standard Report > Audience > Geo > Location > Country (Primary Dimension) reported numbers of Users do not match numbers of users in Google Data Studio (neither with nor without Sessions as a second column)
3. In Google Data Studio report numbers of Users are not being affected by adding Sessions to the table.
4. Creating Custom Reports with Country as rows and Sessions and Users as columns results in exactly the same numbers as in standard GA Audience reporting, removing Users from the Custom Report does not affect number of Sessions reported.
5. In Google Data Studio report a change in the number of Sessions does not happen when I add metrics other than Users (like Pageviews or Goal Conversion)

Below three examples of outputs I get when adding/removing Sessions/Users for the same country selection and for the same date frame (all selections done within the same flat table)

**Example 1**

- Rows (Country) : Belize
- Column1 (Sessions) : 59

**Example 2**

- Rows (Country): Belize
- Column1 (Users) :10

**Example 3**

- Rows (Country): Belize
- Columns

  - Column1 (Sessions) : 20
  - Column2 (Users) : 10

It seems the described behavior might have something to do with the scopes of the metrics, as adding the metrics with Hit or Session scope does not affect the Session numbers in my table.

Can you please let me know what can be causing that behavior?

I googled quite extensively and checked on Google Analytics forums - so far I wasn't able to find anything that would answer my questions.

I am more than happy to perform other tests in order to debug the process further.

Comment: It sounds to me like there might be some data sampling going on.  Have you tried looking at a smaller date range such as the past two days to reduce the amount of data being pulled back?  Have you tried setting up a custom report in GA to see what data is shown there?

Comment: Hi Brian, I tried both of the suggestions with the same results as described. I will keep trying to figure out where the issue lies. Do you think there might be two different tables in Data Studio servers that feed the data in depending on the metric selection so one of the data sets would be a pre-aggregated table and the other based on sampling?